# How can I get the error message of Python/vscode debugging inside a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm using [this workflow](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python) to debug a generic Python application inside a Docker container with vscode.

If i introduce an error to my main.py, such as importing a package that doesn't exist, and press F5 to debug in VSCode, after building the docker image, it fails silently and doesn't provide any useful error message.

e.g:

> Executing task: docker-run: debug <
> docker run -dt -P --name "projectname-dev" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" -v "c:\Users\tim.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1317843341\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy:/debugpy:ro" --entrypoint "python3" "projectname:latest" <
> add88efdff111ae904a38f3d52a52d8191a95f1d53c931a032326ed2958218b3
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

If i remove the error, I have working code, and by running it manually

> docker run projectname

I can see the code works.

However it still fails to debug in vscode, failing silently. A breakpoint set on the first line is never reached. There is no message produced at all from vscode.

How can I see the error message in this case?

Launch.json:

```
 version: '3.4'

services:
  projectname:
    image: projectname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 main.py "]
    ports:
      - 5678:5678
```

docker-compose.debug.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  projectname:
    image: projectname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 main.py "]
    ports:
      - 5678:5678
```

main.py (Minimum viable):

```
import time
import requests 
import json

#import package_that_doesnt_exist

time_look_back = 60*15 # last 15min
time_to_fetch=int(time.time()-time_look_back)
print(time_to_fetch)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.7-alpine3.14

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apk add postgresql-dev 
RUN apk add musl-dev
RUN apk add gcc

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: I think you launch.json is wrong. Could you please fix it while I investigate your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this approach and hope it's suitable for you; if it's not, I will be happy to fix it.

**launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5678,
        "host": "localhost",
        "pathMappings": [
          {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
          }
        ],
        "justMyCode": false,
        "subProcess": true,
        "redirectOutput": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

**docker-compose.yml**

(I usually use ptvsd for debugging inside containers)

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  projectname:
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
    image: projectname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install ptvsd && python main.py"]
    ports:
      - 5678:5678
```

In the **Dockerfile**, I exposed the port 5678 before the CMD (see only the relevant part)

```
USER appuser

EXPOSE 5678

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

**main.py**

```py
import time
import requests 
import json
import os

if bool(int(os.environ.get('DEBUG',0))):
    import ptvsd
    ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 5678))
    print("--- PTVS ATTACHED, press F5 on VSCode to start Debugging")
    ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

#import package_that_doesnt_exist

time_look_back = 60*15 # last 15min
time_to_fetch=int(time.time()-time_look_back)
print(time_to_fetch)
```

---

Now, launching the compose up with the error package **uncommented** and env **DEBUG=0**:
[image: error in console]

Launching the compose up with the error package **commented** and env **DEBUG=0**:

[image: output in console]

Launching the compose up with the error **uncommented** and env **DEBUG=1**:

[image: output in console]

then using F5 to start debugging

[image: error in debug]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Making those changes and pressing F5 to run, I get the following error: https://i.imgur.com/pFNy2Ul.png

Comment: Have you started the container with "docker-compose up" before pressing F5?

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks again Mattia.

Comment: My pleasure Tim